# Monit won't start: "Cannot translate '<hostname>' to FQDN name -- nodename nor servname provided"

Tags: mac-osx, monit, osx-lion

I installed monit-5.3.2 on OS X 10.7 but haven't been able to get it running.

When I run **sudo monit -t** I get:

```
monit: Cannot translate 'hakan' to FQDN name -- nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Control file syntax OK
```

When I run **sudo monit restart all** I get:

```
monit: Cannot translate 'hakan' to FQDN name -- nodename nor servname provided, or not known
monit: Cannot connect to the monit daemon. Did you start it with http support?
```

'hakan' is my hostname.

Here is my */etc/monitrc*:

```
set daemon 60
set idfile /tmp/monit.id
set statefile /tmp/monit.state
set mailserver localhost
set alert systems@abcd.net
set httpd port 2812 and use address localhost
```

Any ideas? I've had no luck finding this on Google. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your hostname `hakan` registered in DNS?  What do you get if you type `host hakan` on the command line?  Is it listed in your [/etc/hosts](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291) file as a fully qualified name (that means `<hostname>.domain`, instead of/in addition to just `<hostname>`).

Comment: If I type 'host hakan' I receive: 'Host hakan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)'. It's not in /etc/hosts either. How would I add it?

Comment: The combination of the above comment and the answer below solved it for me. Thank you for your help larsks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an error of `getaddrinfo`, which is called by monit to figure out the fqdn of your server.

You must not have fqdn set up in your dns for your server.if you do not control the dns server, you may work around it by adding an entry in /etc/hosts like so:

```
192.168.x.y hakan hakan.local.domain
```

where the first one is your server ip.